# How to prevent strip from removing ar archive's index?

Tags: strip, binutils

I wrote a **library** that contains `a.c` and `b.c`, and another program `c.c` that uses this library. I have archived the **library** using `ar` to distribute it. Here are the commands I use:

```sh
gcc -g -c -o a.o a.c    # Compile a.c
gcc -g -c -o b.o b.c    # Compile b.c
ar r ab.a a.o b.o       # Generate library ab.a

gcc -o c c.c ab.a       # Compile c.c
```

Everything works fine until now. But I want to strip some sections in `ab.a` (e.g. debug info, internal functions), so I run `strip --keep-symbol=... ab.a` on the library. Now I cannot compile c.c any more. The error I get is:

```
+ gcc -o c c.c ab.a
/usr/bin/ld: ab.a: error adding symbols: archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I run `ranlib ab.a` after strip, everything works fine. My question is: is it possible to change the arguments in the `strip` command, so that I do not need to run `ranlib ab.a`?

---

#### Complete example

`a.c`:

```c
int a1()
{
    return 1;
}

int a2()
{
    return 2;
}
```

`b.c`:

```c
int b1()
{
    return 3;
}

int b2()
{
    return 4;
}
```

`c.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a1();
int a2();
int b1();
int b2();

int main()
{
    printf("%d ", a1());
    printf("%d ", a2());
    printf("%d ", b1());
    printf("%d\n", b2());
}
```

Bash script to the "archive has no index" error:

```sh
gcc -g -c -o a.o a.c
gcc -g -c -o b.o b.c
ar r ab.a a.o b.o
strip --keep-symbol={a1,a2,b1,b2} ab.a
# ranlib ab.a
gcc -o c c.c ab.a
./c
```

Run the bash script

- Run the bash script directly -> see the error
- Comment the `strip` line -> success (symbols not stripped)
- Uncomment the `ranlib` line -> success

Software versions I am using:

- gcc (GCC) 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)
- GNU ar version 2.35-18.fc33
- GNU strip version 2.35-18.fc33
- GNU ranlib version 2.35-18.fc33